# How JVM can call main() method without argument . No Error Why?

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

We create a method with argument.  eg: void sample(int a)     ...Can i call to sample method without int
 argument ?  No , we will get error......then how JVM call main() without string array argument ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Who says the `main()` method is called *without* any argument? An empty `String` array is passed to adhere to the method signature. If you pass any other arguments to the program, then they are added to this array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(args);
    System.out.println(args.length);
}
```

O/P :

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@5d888759
0
```

Comment: @sibikilivayil - Nope. For `main()`, the arguments are passed by the JVM while / just before invoking `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

main(new String[0]);
Like this JVM calling the main method by pasing object of array of string with 0 size.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Try to provide more explanation to your answers. See [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your answer.